# API Gateway SNS integration failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, urlencode

everyone!

I'm having an issue with an SNS integration on an API Gateway that I've created. I have a third party sending webhooks to my API Gateway. I want to pass the body of this request to an SNS topic. The webhooks are being sent with a content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded as seen in the log below.

```
(someuuid) Method request headers: {CloudFront-Viewer-Country=GB, CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer=false, CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer=false, User-Agent=Amazon CloudFront, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer=false, Host=<myapiid>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, X-Forwarded-Port=443, Date=Thu, 27 Jul 2023 09:38:41 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=<randomkey>, Via=1.0 <randomid>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), X-Amz-Cf-Id=<randomid>, X-Forwarded-For=<thirdpartyip>, <anotherip>, CloudFront-Viewer-ASN=50292, CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer=true, Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded}

(someuuid) Method request body before transformations: {
    "ActionId": "18",
    "Action": "Employee Deleted",
    "EmployeeId": "PW9999",
    "UniqueKey": "6a532ba4-3fc0-44c4-a27b-9bf338f8a04b"
}

(someuuid) Endpoint request URI: https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Publish&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<awsaccountid>:<snsTopicArn>&Message=%7B%22ActionId%22:%2218%22,%22Action%22:%22Employee+Deleted%22,%22EmployeeId%22:%22PW9999%22,%22UniqueKey%22:%226a532ba4-3fc0-44c4-a27b-9bf338f8a04b%22%7D&Subject=<thirdparty>-webhook

(someuuid) Endpoint request body after transformations: {
    "ActionId": "18",
    "Action": "Employee Deleted",
    "EmployeeId": "PW9999",
    "UniqueKey": "6a532ba4-3fc0-44c4-a27b-9bf338f8a04b"
}

(someuuid) Sending request to https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Publish&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<awsAccountId>:<snsTopicId>&Message=%7B%22ActionId%22:%2218%22,%22Action%22:%22Employee+Deleted%22,%22EmployeeId%22:%22PW9999%22,%22UniqueKey%22:%226a532ba4-3fc0-44c4-a27b-9bf338f8a04b%22%7D&Subject=<thirdparty>-webhook

(someuuid) Received response. Status: 400, Integration latency: 4 ms

(someuuid) Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-RequestId=<requestid>, Content-Type=text/xml, Content-Length=282, Date=Thu, 27 Jul 2023 09:38:40 GMT}

(someuuid) Endpoint response body before transformations: <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MalformedQueryString</Code>
    <Message>Keys may not contain {</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId><requestid></RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I've tried to replicate this error with Postman sending the body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and entering the same parameters, this results in a urlencoded string being sent to the SNS topic which works. I've also tried as a raw body object with content-type `application/json` which works too.

I tried to google around and got some recommendations around changing the integration config which is written in cloudformation. I've tried the two configurations below which both result in the same error.

```yaml
Integration:
        Type: AWS
        Credentials: !GetAtt RestApiRole.Arn
        Uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:sns:action/Publish"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        RequestParameters: 
          integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded: !Sub "Message=$util.urlEncode($input.body)"
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: "200"
            ResponseTemplates: #default response
              application/json: '{"status": "OK"}'
```

and

```yaml
Uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:sns:action/Publish"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Join ["", ["'", !Ref SNSTopic, "'"]]
          integration.request.querystring.Subject: "'<thirdparty>-webhook'"
          integration.request.querystring.Message: method.request.body
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: "200"
            ResponseTemplates: #default response
```

Long story short, I need a way of transforming the body of the webhook so that it can be passed to my SNS topic as a valid URL. Has anyone come across this before?